# Shorter fetch into objects mysqli/php

Tags: php, mysqli

I currently have the following

```
<?php while($book = $query->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
```

I can then create a new object by passing $book into a new Book object, as following

```
<?php $book = new Book($book); ?>
```

However, when I attempt to do the following

```
<?php while($book = new Book($query->fetch_assoc())) : ?>
```

I appear to enter an infinite loop. Is this possible and if so, how? Cheers guys.

Comment: Because at some point you will create new objects and pass `NULL` as value to the constructor, but you still create an object, which will enter the loop

Comment: `$book = new Book($query->fetch_assoc())` is always casted into `true` so it's infinite loop. I don't think it's possible to do anything inside `while()`

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks Inurosen.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle Also see: https://3v4l.org/idJYI

Answer (score 0):

The new operator always returning an object instance that is evaluated as *truthy* in your while loop has already been mentioned in the comments to your question.

The mysqli extension provides you with a [mechanism to return records as instances of your (user-defined) class](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

```
while( null!==($book=$query->fetch_object('Book') )
```